# Compare 2 tables with results as a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I have 2 tables, Users and Admins.  Users has userID, userName, and fullName.  Admins has storeID and userID.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a query that would return results that list all userIDs, userNames, fullNames, and a user defined column isAdmin that would be 0 or 1 if that particular userID is found in the Admins table.

I believe it should be possible, but I'm just drawing a blank at the moment.  This will be in a stored procedure so I considered just creating temporary tables for each possibility of just a regular user or only Admins and go from there.  But I would really prefer if it were all in 1 temporary table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know `OUTER JOIN`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select u.*, case when a.userid is null then 0 else 1 end as isadmin
from users u
left join admins a on a.userid = u.userid
```